# Populate multiple gridview from 1 stored procedure

Tags: gridview

I have a stored procedure with 2 select statements, so it returns 2 tables. On my aspx page I have 2 gridviews and I wish to populate then using this stored procedure. The first one gets populated but it doesnt find the columns for second table. Any idea how to this on client side. I know how to do it in C#. Thanks!

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" 
        GridLines="Vertical" >
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        GridLines="Vertical" >
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WPSConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="EXEC ClearanceReportProc" ></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Most likely you are getting a dataset which can contain more than one table.  By default it will return the first table.  You need the syntax to get to the second.

Comment: Yes, by default it is getting the first one, that is how my first gridview gets populated. But second doesnt.

Comment: You are referring to the same name SqlDataSource both times.  Are you getting a repeat the second time or nothing?  In code behind did you verify there is a second table with columns and rows?

Comment: I am using SQL to create the stored proc. Look at the code, that is how i am calling it. Yes it returns 2 tables. When I execute it in SQL Server Management studio.

Comment: What do you mean by "Are you getting a repeat the second time or nothing?"

Comment: I just don't know how to be more clear.  GridView1 and GridView2 both have the same DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1".  You need to point GridView2 to the second table (and be sure that DataSourceID has a second table).

Comment: OK. yes both Gridview1 and 2 are pointing to the same DataSourceID. How do I point gridview2 to second table without using codebehind?

Comment: What have you tried?   Did you try .Tables[1] per my answer?  What syntax do you use in C# that makes it work?

Comment: If the code behind syntax does not working in XAML then most likely that means XAML does not support that syntax.  Since a DataSouce also support update and insert it is not really built for multiple DataTables - is it?   Did you try splitting it into two DataSource1 and DataSource2?

Comment: The DataSourceID of 'GridView6' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'SqlDataSource2.Tables[1]' could not be found. 
I get this error if i assign .Tables[1] to Gridview2

Comment: Then I think you are going to need to split you StoredProcedure and have SqlDataSource1 and SqlDataSource2.  With update and insert features a datasource is just not designed for more than one table.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly have mutiple DataTables in the DataSet I think the syntax is DataSet.Tables[0] DataSet.Tables[1]

Comment: This will in the code behind, but I am not using sql in my code-behind. I want to be able to do it on the aspx page itself, if possible. If not then I will have to it in code-behind, get it in Dataset using SQL adapter and then bind to the tables to respective gridviews.

Comment: If you are not using SQL then explain Stored Procedure.